# incompatible types when assigning to type `'struct LocationArray *[(sizetype)(numberOfLoc)]'` from type 'struct LocationArray *'|

Tags: c, struct

Why am I getting this error?:
`incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct LocationArray *[(sizetype)(numberOfLoc)]' from type 'struct LocationArray *'|`
in the following line in `main()`?

```
 myArray = (LocationArray*)malloc(numberOfLoc*sizeof(LocationArray));
```

**`Code:`**

```
//structure Location
typedef struct Location{
    char locName[35];
    char locDesc[85];
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} LocationArray;

 int main()
    {
        printf("How many locations would you like to be inside the array?\n");
        int numberOfLoc = 0; //variable for storing the size of the LocationArray
        scanf("%d", &numberOfLoc); //gets the user input and stores in numerOfLoc

        LocationArray *myArray[numberOfLoc]; //declares a LocationArray with the size of numberOfLoc
        myArray = (LocationArray*)malloc(numberOfLoc*sizeof(LocationArray));

        //Print the menu
        printMenu(&myArray);

        //Free the pointer
        free(myArray);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocationArray *myArray[numberOfLoc];` should be `LocationArray *myArray;`.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks! @keithmo. One more question: how can I check if the size of array of structures is full or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "full or not". Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to check if the size of `myArray` is full or not, i.e. if the array is filled completely. How can I do that?

Comment: There's nothing built into the language for this, you'll need to do it yourself.